# How to call a javascript function with a css button?

Tags: javascript, css

I am writing a script to color a text, the main idea is that when someone click in the button called: Change color1 then my text change its color, the code for this is the follow one:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change color1</button>
```

That calls the next function:

```
function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}
```

I would like to achieve the same result with the button called: Change color2, that I created using css, the problem is that I don't know how to call the function that reload the page with this one.

In the case of the first button its very clear how to achieve this by:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change color1</button>
```

but with the second one I am not sure:

```
<button class="button button1">Change color2</button>
```

I tried:

```
<button class="myFunction()">Change color2</button>
```

But I failed, therefore I would like to fix this problem.

my complete code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><script src="./code33_files/lodash.js"></script> 
</head><body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea cols="150" rows="15" id="texto" >
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXA.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa2"
"RBD|X3|RBD|C|92173~GJHGXC.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGWO.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
"RBD|X|RBD|C|92173~GJHGX4.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa"
"RBD|X3|RBD3|C|92173~GJHGX6.NAYE" "SAMBORNSiPOSSSTHRa1"
</textarea>
<div id="out1"></div>
<style>
body {background-color:blue;}
#out1 {
  text-align: left;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: LightSlateGray;
  width: 1000px;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 25px solid navy;
  margin: 25px;
}
.button {
    background-color: Green;
    border: 4px solid Cyan; 
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 4px 34px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px black;

}

</style>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change color1</button>

<button class="button button1">Change color2</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}
var text = document.getElementById("texto").value;
var splitWords = text.split(/[["\|~]/);
var cleanArray  = _.remove(splitWords, function (word) {return word !== '' && word !== ' ' && word !== '\n'});
var dict = cleanArray.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (p[c] === undefined) {
        p[c] = 1;
    } else {
        p[c]++;
    }
    return p;
},{});
console.log(dict);
var filtered = Object.keys(dict).reduce(function (filtered, key) {
    if (dict[key] > 1) filtered[key] = dict[key];
    return filtered;
}, {});
var colorWords = Object.keys(filtered)
colors = ["AliceBlue","AntiqueWhite","Aqua","Aquamarine","Azure","Beige","Bisque","Black","BlanchedAlmond","Blue","BlueViolet","Brown","BurlyWood","CadetBlue","Chartreuse","Chocolate","Coral","CornflowerBlue","Cornsilk","Crimson","Cyan","DarkBlue","DarkCyan","DarkGoldenRod","DarkGray","DarkGrey","DarkGreen","DarkKhaki","DarkMagenta","DarkOliveGreen","DarkOrange","DarkOrchid","DarkRed","DarkSalmon","DarkSeaGreen","DarkSlateBlue","DarkSlateGray","DarkSlateGrey","DarkTurquoise","DarkViolet","DeepPink","DeepSkyBlue","DimGray","DimGrey","DodgerBlue","FireBrick","FloralWhite","ForestGreen","Fuchsia","Gainsboro","GhostWhite","Gold","GoldenRod","Gray","Grey","Green","GreenYellow","HoneyDew","HotPink","IndianRed","Indigo","Ivory","Khaki","Lavender","LavenderBlush","LawnGreen","LemonChiffon","LightBlue","LightCoral","LightCyan","LightGoldenRodYellow","LightGray","LightGrey","LightGreen","LightPink","LightSalmon","LightSeaGreen","LightSkyBlue","LightSlateGray","LightSlateGrey","LightSteelBlue","LightYellow","Lime","LimeGreen","Linen","Magenta","Maroon","MediumAquaMarine","MediumBlue","MediumOrchid","MediumPurple","MediumSeaGreen","MediumSlateBlue","MediumSpringGreen","MediumTurquoise","MediumVioletRed","MidnightBlue","MintCream","MistyRose","Moccasin","NavajoWhite","Navy","OldLace","Olive","OliveDrab","Orange","OrangeRed","Orchid","PaleGoldenRod","PaleGreen","PaleTurquoise","PaleVioletRed","PapayaWhip","PeachPuff","Peru","Pink","Plum","PowderBlue","Purple","RebeccaPurple","Red","RosyBrown","RoyalBlue","SaddleBrown","Salmon","SandyBrown","SeaGreen","SeaShell","Sienna","Silver","SkyBlue","SlateBlue","SlateGray","SlateGrey","Snow","SpringGreen","SteelBlue","Tan","Teal","Thistle","Tomato","Turquoise","Violet","Wheat","White","WhiteSmoke","Yellow","YellowGreen"]
for (i = 0; i < colorWords.length; i++) { 
    word=colorWords[i];
    text = text.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b", 'g'), '<span style="color:'+colors[Math.floor((Math.random(148) * colors.length) + 1)]+'">'+colorWords[i]+'</span>');
}
console.log(text);
document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `onclick="..."` in your second button the same as in the first one?

Comment: You cannot reload the page using css

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to reload the page? Wouldn't this undo any modification made?

Comment: you want to use jquery with your css class. Your jquery will perform the change based n whatever color button was selected

Comment: If you want a button to reload the page without using script make it type="submit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<button class="button button1">Change color2</button>
```

To:

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="myFunction();">Change color2</button>
```

or you can run jQuery code to add an event listener:

```
<script>
 $("button.button").click(function(){
  myFunction();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You should include a vanilla JS solution as well, since the question isn't currently using jQuery, and doesn't have the jQuery tag

Comment: just a quick question if I use the second one option, should I need to use an import in order to use jQuery?, anyhow thanks for the support this was really helpful.

Comment: Yes. In order to use jQuery, you must include the library on your page. You can use a simple <script src="/path/to/your/jQuery.js"></script> or an async loader.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: @neo33 (And future readers) This is just my opinion, but I would *highly* recommend getting familiar with Vanilla JS before using a library like jQuery. You'll find problems much easier to solve if you understand how the language you are using works.

Comment: @Jacob Gray, I Agree, I appreciate your suggestion, I will research a little bit more  to get more familiarized with Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

You tried adding the function inside class `<button class="myFunction()">Change color2</button>` which is not valid,  change it and add the function to the onclick like `<button class="button button1" onclick="myFunction()">Change color2</button>` and that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

change the second button from:

```
<button class="myFunction()">Change color2</button>
```

to

```
<button OnClick="myFunction()">Change color2</button>
```